# how to change/clean this particular row value[datatype string] in my R dataframe

Tags: sql, r, database

I have a sample dataframe where row 1 and row 2 for all columns[except 1st] contains data like below:

[image]

How can I simply keep figures like

option 1: only numbers within 84.92 crore (US$13 million)[5]" so result is "13"

option 2: only numbers and units within 84.92 crore (US$13 million)[5]" so result is "13 million"

at first i tried to find starting position so that i can apply substr later but it's giving error:

```
>grep("US$",df[1,1],fixed=TRUE))
integer(0)
```

is there any way to dump the data in sqlite or use sqldf package etc to do this clean-up...something ? this string by string clean-up is not looking good to me.

Comment: Are you missing some quote marks? I see you write `within ..."` but you must mean `within "..."`, right?

Comment: and this if you want the units also `gsub('.*US\\$(\\d*.*)\\).*', '\\1', x)`

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub('.*US\\$(.*)\\).*', '\\1', x)
[1] "13 million"  "11 million"  "1.6 million"
[4] "5.6 million

gsub('.*US\\$(.*) .*', '\\1', x)
[1] "13"  "11"  "1.6" "5.6"
```

**Data**

```
x <- c("<U+20B9>84.92 crore (US$13 million)[5]", "<U+20B9>680 million (US$11 million)", 
       "<U+20B9>100 crore (US$1.6 million)[4]","<U+20B9>350 million (US$5.6 million)")
```